# eclipse - create custom mapping for "toggle source/header"

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-cdt

There is an Eclipse shortcut called **Toggle Source/Header** that toggles the view from *filename*.**cpp** to *filename*.**h**

I want to toggle between the source file (**.c**) and the same file pre-processed (**.pp**).

Is there a way to create such a mapping between two files of arbitrary suffixes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not aware of a way to do this currently.

You're welcome to [file a feature request](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/enter_bug.cgi?product=CDT) for this, or even better, contribute a patch that adds support for this.

Comment: @Adrian: If you know C++, Java is not that hard to pick up. The learning curve is more with understanding the codebase. It helps to have someone answer questions that come up about the codebase. I'm happy to try and help there :)